# Does setTimeout continues even after changing page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 pages, Home page and Edit page.

I used a function which will auto log out the user after a certain amount of time of inactivity.

The function is only used in Home page and not Edit page.

Below is the function code.

```
    // Set timeout variables.
    var timoutWarning = 10000; 
    var timoutNow = 30000; 


    var warningTimer;
    var timeoutTimer;

    // Start timers.
    function StartTimers() {
        console.log("Start TImer");
        warningTimer = setTimeout("IdleWarning()", timoutWarning);
        timeoutTimer = setTimeout("SignOut()", timoutNow);
        $( "#timeout" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false
    });
    }

    // Reset timers.
    function ResetTimers() {
        clearTimeout(warningTimer);
        clearTimeout(timeoutTimer);
        StartTimers();
        $( "#timeout" ).dialog("close")
        console.log("Reset TImer");
 }


    // Show idle timeout warning dialog.
    function IdleWarning() {

        $("#timeout").dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            modal: true

        });

    }
```

I called out the function in the Home page by using

```
   <body onload="StartTimers();" onmousemove="ResetTimers();">

<div id="timeout">
    <h1>
        Session About To Timeout</h1>
    <p>
        You will be automatically logged out in a while<br />
    To remain logged in move your mouse
</div>
```

The timer works perfectly fine in the Home page, but after I switch to Edit page ( without the function basically an empty page), I will still get auto log out with or without moving the mouse.

Does that means that the function is still running even after I switch page? If so, is there anything I can do to stop the timer after I switched the page?

p.s I did tried adding in the function and call it in the Edit page, however, even after I kept on moving my mouse I will still get logged out which is why I assume that the function is still running after I switch page.

SOLVED :  its working fine right now after I restart my browser. I believe I might have screwed up somewhere. I apologize to people who invested their time into this question.  The answer to my question based on the comments/answers below is NO. setTimeout DOES NOT continues after changing page.

Comment: When a page is closed, everything dies with the page, including timeouts. What happens when you switch from Home to Edit? Does a refresh happen, or is it more like a single page application? Are you 100% positive that you are not setting a timeout on the Edit page as well?

Comment: Basically its .../home.html and when I clicked on something, it will brings me to .../edit.html (I not sure if a refresh happens). I store the function in timer.js, so I believe that if I did set the time out in Edit page I would have added  <script src="timer.js"></script> in Edit page in which I didnt

Comment: So how exactly does the transition from /home.html to /edit.html happen? Can you share some code maybe?

Comment: Actually its working fine right now after I restart my browser. I didnt get auto log out in edit page anymore. I think I might have screwed up somewhere. Thanks for your time and sorry for wasting your time

Comment: Yeah well, no question is stupid. Just grab a coffee and keep trying :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the browser has fully loaded the second page, and that code isn't on it, that code won't run. That's assuming you're loading the second page 'traditionally' and not pulling it in via AJAX.

I would do the following things:

- Put an `alert("Code running")` in the setTimeout function. That's a very simple way of telling you if the code is running or not.
- Check the source code for your edit page. Make sure you haven't duplicated the code to that page too.

Answer (score 1):

No, timeouts get deleted when you close/refresh the page (just like anything in JavaScript). So your bug must be something else.